# Where's my Entity - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've created an Entity in Symfony2 using:

```
  php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

It says it has correctly generated but I see no changes at all. There doesn't seem to be any changes in the bundle folder.

```
  Entity generation  

  Generating the entity code: OK

  You can now start using the generated code!
```

Where do these get put and is there a way to check the 'installed entities' or something?

Also, where are the Yaml files generated (I chose Yaml)? I don't see any new ones.

Comment: Is this the entire console output?

Comment: Of course it's not. There are no other errors, it tells me everything is correct. Where should the files be if there were no errors (as it tells me there are no errors)?

Comment: If you don't copy/paste the entire console output from the moment you entered the command nobody will be able to help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities are stored in the bundle in a /Entity folder as one PHP class file.

The Yaml files are stored in the bundle in a /Resources/config/doctrine/{table-name}.orm.yml file.

My problem was due to using a bundle with a similar name to one of the default bundles, I actually created an entity in one of the default Symfony bundles which is why I couldn't find it and why there was no error message. I'm guessing nobody would ever have been able to help with that!

Also, this show current 'mapped' entities:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

Easy when you know how. Can't believe nobody knew this. Took me ages to find it.